# A special garment for prayer

Tags: tefilla, clothing

I heard somewhere that you're supposed to have a special garment for prayer. 
Where is the source for this?

Comment: See ShA OC 91 .

Comment: R. Rasson Arussi writes that a special garment is not necessary for prayer: http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=183977

Comment: @mevaqesh That's not quite what he says. He says there is no garment which is special for prayer other than a Talit, and arguably he's only saying this according to R Kappah

Comment: Correct. That's part of why I didn't post it as an answer. I indeed simplified his statement.

Answer (score 3):

It is mentioned by Tur ([OC §98](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A6%D7%97))

> וכתיב ולעבדו בכל לבבכם וכי יש עבודה בלב אלא איזו היא עבודה שהיא בלב הוי אומר זו תפלה ולכן צריך ליזהר שתהא דוגמת הקרבן... וראוי הוא שיהיו לו מלבושים נאים מיוחדים לתפלה

Comment: A translation would greatly improve this answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

It's in סימן צא regarding the requirement of wearing a belt, whether the reson is halachic שלא יהא לבו רואה ערותו or for a mitzvah of הכון לקראת אלוקיך see בית יוסף on the tur ,

The שו'ע סימן צא סעיף ב

> צריך לאזור אזור בשעת התפלה אפילו יש לו אבנט שאין לבו רואה את הערוה משום הכון אבל שאר ברכות מותר לברך בלא חגורה מאחר שיש לו מכנסיים.
>   הגה: ואין לבו רואה את הערוה

So if the reason is הכון, this means that we prepair ourselves to be set, with the correct respect to stand before Hashem, it requires an extra special garment that one doesn't wear all the time

Look at the mishna berura there,lhalacha.

Comment: The shulhan arukh says nothing (in your quote) about a special garment one doesn't wear all the time.

Comment: The אזור is the extra special garment since he already has an אבנט